# Angular + Typescript: Add to array, ng-repeat adds blank row

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

Trying to add a new object to an array and have it show up in an ng-repeat div.  I add the object, look at the array in Chrome's dev tools and can see the new object in there, but the ng-repeat section just has a blank row.  I've search throughout StackOverflow, implemented many solutions and still have this problem.

HTML:

> ```
>    <div ng-repeat="subItem in ec.mainItem.SubItems">
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col-md-12">
>                 <div class="row">
>                     <div class="col-md-3 h4">
>                         <button class="btn-link">{{subItem.Name}}</button>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="col-md-6">
>                         {{subItem.Description}}
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> ```

ItemCtrl.ts

```
module MainItemApp {
    'use strict'

    export class MainItemEntryCtrl implements IMainItemCtrl {
        static $inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'ItemSvc'];
        public mainItem: MainItem; //this has an array on it named SubItems

        public sub_item_name: string;
        public sub_item_description: string;
        public sub_item_date: Date;
        public sub_item_start_date: Date;
        public sub_item_end_date: Date;
        public sub_item_descriptive_location: string;
        public sub_item_short_location: string;

        constructor($scope, $routeParams: IItemEntryRouteParams, itemSvc: ItemSvc) {
            this.id= this.getId($routeParams.id);

            if (this.id!= undefined) {
                itemSvc.getMainItem(this.id).then(
                    (data) => this.mainItem = data);
            }
        }

        addSubItem() {
            var subItem = {
                id: '',
                name: this.sub_item_name,
                itemDate: this.sub_item_date,
                startDate: this.sub_item_start_date,
                endDate: this.sub_item_end_date,
                description: this.sub_item_description,
                descriptiveLocation: this.sub_item_descriptive_location,
                shortLocation: this.sub_item_short_location,
                geoLat: '',
                geoLong: '',
                groupItems: []
            };

            this.mainItem.SubItems.push(subItem);
        }
}
```

When I click a button, AddSubItem runs, the item gets created and after the push, I can hover over subItems and see the array has two objects, the one I loaded with and the one I pushed, but the HTML that's generated gives me this:

> ```
>    <div ng-repeat="subItem in ec.mainItem.SubItems">
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col-md-12">
>                 <div class="row">
>                     <div class="col-md-3 h4">
>                         <button class="btn-link">Some Item</button>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="col-md-6">
>                         Some Description
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <div ng-repeat="subItem in ec.mainItem.SubItems">
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col-md-12">
>                 <div class="row">
>                     <div class="col-md-3 h4">
>                         <button class="btn-link"></button>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="col-md-6">
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> ```

Any ideas?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are setting `this.sub_item_description`, so why would it be anything but `undefined`?

Comment: Its because you are accessing the property names `description` and `name` as `Description` and `Name`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, bad post, I figured it out (isn't it always like that, as soon as you make a fool of yourself and ask, you figure it out).  My data was coming back from the API with capitalized property names (i.e. Name, Description) and I was adding an object where the names were lowercase (i.e. name, description) so of course there was nothing to show in the newly added row.  So I synced up the names coming from my API with the names in the Typescript classes and everything is working now.  So of course when I searched for the answer, I couldn't find it: no one posted "Hey dummy! Check the casing on your properties!"

So I think I will leave this up just in case someone else runs across the same problem and it sparks them to check their casing.